# Using ZXing Mobile in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

currently trying to build an app using ZXing Mobile for Xamarin Forms.

The code compiled without issue. But when trying to run on Android device, I got the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occcured.
```

The log shows the following:

```
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayTopText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.TopText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayBottomText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.BottomText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.ShowFlashButton'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayTopText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.TopText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayBottomText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.BottomText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.ShowFlashButton'
```

This is how i implemented:

```
scanButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
                {
                    AutoRotate = false,
                    UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false,
                    TryHarder = true
                };
                var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(options)
                {
                    DefaultOverlayTopText = "Align the barcode within the frame",
                    DefaultOverlayBottomText = string.Empty,
                    DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton = true
                };
                // Navigate to our scanner page
                await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);

                scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                {
                    // Stop scanning
                    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

                    // Pop the page and show the result
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await Navigation.PopAsync();
                        await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                    });
                };
            };
```

Also added the following in Android's Main activity, right above Xamarin's own Init :

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Zxing are you using? Nuget or component? Also are you asking for the permissions for the Camera?

Comment: The version is 2.2.9. Installed through Nuget. Yes the permission is added on the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and found the error was more related to the navigation.

You are using

```
await Navigation.PushAsync (scanPage);
```

Make sure you are calling this method from a page which contains a NavigationPage if not you will have a crash.

To fix this you can use

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync (scanPage);
```

instead, which doesn't require a NavigationPage and the resulting page displayed will be modal. Using the line above you will need to also change the way you "pop" the view.

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync (true);
```

**Note:**

These messages you will appear in the logs even when working.

```
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayTopText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.TopText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayBottomText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.BottomText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.ShowFlashButton'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayTopText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.TopText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayBottomText' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.BottomText'
[0:] Binding: 'DefaultOverlayShowFlashButton' property not found on 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay', target property: 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingDefaultOverlay.ShowFlashButton'
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know the error is about the missing `NavigationPage`. Wonder why the error message does not implied that..